# how to fix err_content_decoding_failed when dynamic compressing?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, compression

I'm working on a ASP.Net website, and are currently optimizing it.
I'm trying to enable dynamic content compression to it, but it won't work.

I get

> Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.

- On my development environment it works well.

  - I've built the project in release mode 
    I've added the dynamic content compression module, enabled dynamic content compression and checked that this is what i receive.
- I have an AWS EC2 server windows 2008 R2 with IIS installed.

  - I've built the project in release mode, and publish it to a folder, which i deploy to the server.
  - I've tried with the same web.config file as i have on the developer machine, but no luck there

Added this to web.config:

```
<httpCompression
    directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
    dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90"
    dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80"
    maxDiskSpaceUsage="100" minFileSizeForComp="2700"
    noCompressionForRange="true"
    sendCacheHeaders="false"
    staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="100"
    staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80"
    >
    <scheme name="gzip"
        dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" />
```

Anybody have an idea of what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Tried running the request through fiddler and got the response:
"The content could not be decompressed.

The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."

Comment: did you figure out what the issue was with this?  I am getting the same issue . . .

Answer (score 8):

We encountered this problem caused IIS Temporary Compressed Files which were corrupt/truncated due to the disk running out of space:

1. Run `inetmgr`
2. Go to the machine, **Compression** feature
3. Delete the contents of the **Cache directory**

Answer (score 5):

A colleague of mine had this exact same problem.

He was running his application with a non-standard application pool identity. For the sake of this solution I will call that identity `SomeOtherApplicationPoolIdentity`.

The problem was that it was lacking permissions to a sub-folder in his cache directory (to see what cache directory IIS uses, go to the IIS Manager, click the top-level tree node, click on Compression; by default it is `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files`):

[image]

Inside of `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files`, he was missing permissions for a sub-folder named, `SomeOtherApplicationPoolIdentity`, contextually named according to his application pool identity, so he just inherited permissions from the parent folder from that sub-folder and it worked, because the parent folder generally grants permissions to the `IIS_IUSRS`, `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`, and local administrative user account.

Comment: Thanks for this!  APP pool user set to LOCAL_SERVICE.  Wiped temp folder contents, and added LOCAL_SERVICE with full permissions for temp folder seems to of resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

try to specify dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false"

I was trying to use dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" because I thought it will cause my cached objects to be saved compressed - so that they can be served as smaller files, but got the same error...

```
<!--http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/urlcompression-->
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
<httpCompression 
  directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"
  dynamicCompressionDisableCpuUsage="90"
  dynamicCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80"
  maxDiskSpaceUsage="100"
  minFileSizeForComp="2700"
  noCompressionForRange="true"
  sendCacheHeaders="false"
  staticCompressionDisableCpuUsage="100"
  staticCompressionEnableCpuUsage="80">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/atom+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/rss+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xaml+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="application/xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="image/svg+xml" enabled="true" />
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

> http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/urlcompression
>
> The dynamicCompressionBeforeCache attribute specifies whether IIS will
>   dynamically compress content that has not been cached. When the
>   dynamicCompressionBeforeCache attribute is true, IIS dynamically
>   compresses the response the first time a request is made and queues
>   the content for compression. Subsequent requests are served
>   dynamically until the compressed response has been added to the cache
>   directory. Once the compressed response is added to the cache
>   directory, the cached response is sent to clients for subsequent
>   requests. When dynamicCompressionBeforeCache is false, IIS returns the
>   uncompressed response until the compressed response has been added to
>   the cache directory.
>
> Note: If the dynamicCompressionBeforeCache attribute is true when the
>   output cache response has been flushed, dynamic compression will not
>   be performed before the response is put into the output cache.
>   However, if the doDynamicCompression attribute is true, dynamic
>   compression will still occur after the output cache has been filled
>   with the response.

Comment: I am using Glympse and Chrome would return ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED whenever I turned it on. Setting this to false worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

my idea is to check if the application pool user (if you have any specific) has full rights to directory "%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files"