# Getting 'Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED' error after publish MVC 5 website on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

We have recently published our website (MVC 5) on Azure and have noticed that at times, especially when you do Ctrl+F5, the following error comes up: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

[image]

I am really not sure why this is happening on Azure. We have a website hosted on IIS which uses most of the code and settings of this website hosted on Azure and this error does not show on the website hosted on IIS.

I've looked at this [how to fix err_content_decoding_failed when dynamic compressing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112104/how-to-fix-err-content-decoding-failed-when-dynamic-compressing) but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Please can someone assist with this error. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us all the code of `BundleConfig.cs`? Usually this kind of problem does not occur because I see that you have customized `corporate.min.css` and `revolution.min.js`, so guess whether some configuration has been modified.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?